# Limpiar TR y TD vacíos de un HTML con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un problema a la hora de limpiar un HTML con muchos tr y td inútiles.
Este HTML me llega de un programa externo, y debo dejarlo lo más "resposive" que pueda.
Tiene que ser en PHP, por lo que no vale Javascript ni jQuery.
Además, se complica algo más porque algunos td tienen colspan y width... la idea es eliminarlos completamente, por lo que quiero dejar solo los tr y td que tengan algún contenido y además, dejarlos sin ningún atributo.
Posteriormente les daré estilo con CSS.
Pensé que sería "fácil" utilizando expresiones regulares pero no caí en que el símbolo "<" (y muchos otros en el HTML) es un caracter especial... Encontré la función preg_quote que debería escapar estos caracteres especiales, pero si hago esto:

```
$str = preg_quote( "<td width='4'/>", '/' );
echo $str;
```

El resultado que obtengo es: "\"
¡NO LO ENTIENDO!

Pego un trozo del HTML que me llega para que os hagáis una idea mejor.

```html
<table width='707' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr style='height: 1px'>
  <td width='4'/><td width='38'/>
  <td width='8'/><td width='15'/>
  <td width='8'/><td width='8'/>
  <td width='4'/><td width='4'/>
  <td width='4'/><td width='8'/>
  <td width='8'/><td width='8'/>
  <td width='8'/><td width='8'/>
  <td width='4'/><td width='8'/>
  <td width='8'/><td width='4'/>
  <td width='4'/><td width='4'/>
  <td width='23'/><td width='8'/>
  <td width='91'/><td width='4'/>
  <td width='79'/><td width='8'/>
  <td width='4'/><td width='8'/>
  <td width='45'/><td width='8'/>
  <td width='11'/><td width='49'/>
  <td width='8'/><td width='49'/>
  <td width='4'/><td width='11'/>
  <td width='83'/>
  <td width='23'/>
  <td width='4'/>
  <td width='4'/>
  <td width='4'/>
  <td width='23'/>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:18px'>
  <td colspan='19' class='s0'>Datos Establecimiento</td>
  <td/><td/>
  <td/><td/>
  <td/><td/>
```

Comment: las expresiones regulares con html suelen ser traicioneras, podes usar [`DOMdocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/domdocument.loadhtml.php) cargarlo, limpiarlo, incluso tomar la data y transformarlo en otra estructura

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!